# On polynomial equation of fourth order depending on two parameters and bound on a maximal root

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, inequalities

*I would like  to apologize in advance for a too technical question.* Let us consider the following fourth order polynomial equation in $x$:
\begin{eqnarray} 
       F(x) \equiv (2 a p +2)x^4+ (6a(1-a)p^2+(6-12a)p-6)x^3   \nonumber \\
      + p(2(a-2)(a-1)a p^2 + 3(5a^2-9a+2)p +12a-18)x^2  \nonumber \\
  - p^2 ((a-2)(4a^2 - 7a +1)p +9a^2-25a+18)x \nonumber \\
   + (a-2)(a-1)(2a-3)p^3 =0,  \quad  
       (1)
\end{eqnarray}
where real parameters $a$ and $p$  obey inequalities:
\begin{equation} 
  0 < a < 2,  \quad p > 0.   \quad     (2)          
 \end{equation}

**It is necessary to prove** that  for any  $a$ and $p$ obeying   (2),
the  equation (1)
has one and only one solution  $x  = x_{*} =  x_{*}(a,p)$ which satisfies the relation
\begin{equation} 
  x_{*} > 1;  \qquad               (3)   
\end{equation}                                                                                                             moreover, for all $a$ and $p$ (see (2)) this solution obeys the following bound
\begin{equation}
x_{*}  >  x_0 \equiv \frac{1}{2} [(a - 1)p  + 3/2 + \sqrt{d}],  \quad       (4)   
   \end{equation}
where $d = (1 - a)^2 p^2 + (3 - a)p + 9/4$.

**Comment.** The existence of the root  satisfying (3) can be readily proved.
Indeed,  due to (2) we have
\begin{equation}
             F(1) = 2(p+1)^2((a - 2)p-2) < 0.   \qquad     (5)
 \end{equation}
Since   $(2ap+2) > 0$   we get
\begin{equation}
             F(x)    \to  + \infty ,       \qquad          (6)
              \end{equation}
as $x \to  + \infty$. This implies the existence of $x_{+} > 1$ such that
\begin{equation}
                   F(x_{+}) > 1. \qquad  (7)                                                                                                               
             \end{equation}
Applying the intermediate value theorem to the continuous function     $F(x)$  on closed
interval $[1, x_{+}]$  with boundary values given by  (5) and (7)
we find that there exists   $x_{*}$  belonging to interval $(1, x_{+} )$ such that
\begin{equation}
                    F(x_{*}  ) = 0.     \qquad         (8)
                    \end{equation}
So, the existence of the solution to equation (1) satisfying $x_{*}  > 1$ is proved.
Analogous consideration gives us an existence of another root $x_{**}$ ( $F(x_{**}  ) = 0$ )
which satisfies $x_{**}  < 1$.
P.S. This task appears
in solving certain physical problem and here all inequalities  have certain physical meanings.

Comment: There are values of $a$ and $p$ such that equation (1) has four real roots, e.g. for $a = 1.54$, $p = 9$ the roots are approximately $x = -0.5612685895,\; -0.3030493155,\; -0.1540850850,\; 18.59840299$.